# How do I dynamically load the most recent youtube video in a playlist in youtube api v3?

Tags: video, dynamic, youtube, youtube-api

We used to (before 4/20/2015 Youtube code changeover) use this:

This however, no longer works and we get a generic video instead that tells us to go here: https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/6098135?p=yt_devicesupport&hl=en&rd=1

```
    <div id="player"></div>

<script>
    function showVideo(response) {
        if(response.data && response.data.items) {
            var items = response.data.items;
            if(items.length>0) {
                var item = items[0];
                var videoid = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/"+item.id;
                console.log("Latest ID: '"+videoid+"'");
                var video = "<iframe width='200' height='200' src='"+videoid+"' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>"; 
                $('#player').html(video);
            }
        }
    }
</script>
    <script src="https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/AllCoveredInc/uploads?max-results=1&orderby=published&v=2&alt=jsonc&callback=showVideo"></script>
```

Please advise.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the "playlist" you want to get a video from is just a user's uploads, you can get the same info in V3 as long as you have the user's channel ID. If yo don't have the channel ID, you can get it this way:

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet&forUsername={username}&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

(don't forget to register for an api key at console.developers.google.com!)

Once you have the channel ID, you can get a user's latest uploaded video with the search endpoint, like this:

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?order=date&part=snippet&channelId={channel id here}&maxResults=1&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

Note that this is JSON, not JSON-P, so it won't automatically execute your callback; you'll want to either use the Google API javascript client, or a standard ajax library, to make that call, and when the data comes back you can pass it to your showvideo() method manually for processing.

If you're wanting to get videos from a different sort of playlist (i.e. not a user's uploads, but maybe a handcrafted playlist), your call would instead look like this:

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&playlistId=PLid2PnAnKqQEETT-Ppjj5y_PgpcQ8qGaQ&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

Where the long string starting with PL is the playlist ID. Note that the resulting json is in a slightly different form, but still contains video IDs.